# Weird behaviour when assigning a NSMutableArray to another (iOS 6)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray, nsarray, xcode4.6

I'm developing for iOS 6 on Xcode 4.6.1

I'm facing a pretty weird issue. Do `NSMutableArray`s get "linked" in some way when you assign them to another `NSMutableArray`?

Here is my code:

`ViewController.m`

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *one;
    NSMutableArray *two;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    two = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [one addObject:@"item1"];
    [one addObject:@"item2"];
    [one addObject:@"item3"];

    two = one;

    NSLog(@"First log: %@ and %@",one, two);

    [one addObject:@"item4"];

    NSLog(@"Second log: %@ and %@",one, two);
}
```

I just add 3 items to `one`. Then I assign it to `two`. Now when I add another object to `one`, it gets added to `two` as well. Why is this? Are they "linked" in some way?

Here is the log:

```
First log: (
    item1,
    item2,
    item3
) and (
    item1,
    item2,
    item3
)
Second log: (
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    item4
) and (
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    item4
)
```

My workaround was to use a `NSArray` instead of `NSMutableArray` since `NSArray`s are not changeable. But I would really like to know why is this happening? Am I missing something highly obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: This is completely normal and intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the way that objects work in Object-oriented languages is that the name you give an object (`one` and `two`) is just a pointer to the object and not the actual object. When you set an object equal to another it just sets it to be a pointer to the same object.

In Objective-C and some other languages, an object is anything you create with an `*` before the name.

If you want to copy the actual object and not the pointer to the object, you instead want to do:

```
two = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:one];
```

This creates a new Array as `two` and adds all values from `one`.

Comment: Not sure I would say this is an "Object-Oriented language" thing.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Finally I understand :) Guess my basics are pretty weak. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you Pointed Array Two to One ,So it will always show the content of Array One .

Answer (score 1):

```
two = one;
```

It doesn't make a copy. It just makes a reference to the same memory.